# Default property values in Angular2 - constructor or inline?

Tags: angular, oop, typescript, constructor

When creating an object class in angular2, should I initialize values inline or in a constructor? Is there a difference?

```
export class Foo {
  id: string;
  name: string = '';
  url: string = '';
}
```

vs

```
export class Foo {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  url: string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.url = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is all about TypeScript, and not really about angular2 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing a property inline is more concise, and keeps the default value of the property more in context with its declaration.

Initializing a property in the constructor allows you to leverage constructor parameters when you're initializing the property. You can also separate the declaration order from the order in which the values are initialized (in case one property's starting value depends on another one's, for example).

Which one you should use in cases where you don't need the flexibility that the constructor gives you is largely going to be a matter of personal style preference.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in generated JS between the two. When compiling TypeScript compiler just brings values initialized inline inside the constructor.

Try it out here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/